# Getting IllegalStateException when reloading a namespace in the REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

My namespace declaration looks like this:

```
(ns test.foo
  (:use 
    [clj-http.client :only (get) :as client]
    [net.cgrand.enlive-html :only (select) :as html]))
```

It works fine in the REPL, the first time I use it. Then, when I modify the code and try the following in the REPL:

```
(use :reload 'test.foo)
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: get already refers to: #'clj-http.client/get in namespace: test.foo (foo.clj:1)
```

I'm on windows with counterclockwise and also tried with leiningen (lein repl).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not shadow core fns by accident. You have to be explicit about your intent:

```
(ns test.foo
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [get]) ; suppress the shadowing warning
  (:require [clojure.core :as core]) ; allow to still reach clojure.core/get through core/get
  (:use 
    [clj-http.client :only (get) :as client]
    [net.cgrand.enlive-html :only (select) :as html]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Christophe. I guess I couldn't expect better than a Clojure master answering my question ;o)

Comment: While this answer is still perfectly valid, I realized that using :require instead of :use also solves my problem, as long as I always use the prefix specified in :as to call the functions from other namespaces. I personally prefer this alternative.